# I keep getting an unexpected token trying to create a static page in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have checked each tag in html but they don't have any missing tokens but I get an unexpected token '<' when trying to render my component in react

This is my React code

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
function Temp()
{
    return(
        //This is where I get the unexpected token error
        <h1>Test</h1>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Temp/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script
          type="text/babel" 
          src="node_modules">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which version of react/react-dom are you using?

Comment: I am using react 17

Comment: This `src="node_modules"` looks unsettling. Is it really the entire HTML?

Comment: the node modules is the required files for react app files that have the react and react-dom

Comment: I have never seen a setup like that. Did you used a tutorial of some kind?

Comment: yes I followed the react website that asked me to download the node modules

Comment: I was expecting the link to the information about your setup. Also, please show `package.json`

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: I ran `npx create-react-app my-app` and my `index.html` doesn't look like this